# How to init C++ vector/set with array in MS compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, c++11, vector

here is the problem.
I've found out that in C++11 it's possible to init std::vector with array in this way:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

That looks really natural and readable, but the problem is that it doesn't work in MS C++ compiler in Visual Studio 2012. So is this possible to enable this feature in this compiler or should I install newer version of MS compiler(if it exist)?

Comment: install newer version. and yes it exists. the latest for general consumption is visual studio 2013 (even express version) with the November 2013 CTP version of the compiler. you'll have to download and install the CTP version after having installed visual studio 2013.

Comment: @htzfun: you can try your program on online c++ compiler(fully c++11 compliant) here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368(v=vs.120).aspx feature list support in 2013

Comment: The noc CTP of 2013 is a beta release that MS does not consider suitable to build commercial released apps, but rather can be used for testing.  That said, the 2013 non-CTP supports brace init of `vector`, but I vaguely recall there being a bug involving destroying the first element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};` uses an initializer list, not an array. It calls the constructor

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

As far as I know, initializer lists are not supported by your compiler version, so if you want to use them, you have to upgrade. As a workaround, you could declare a temporary array and initialize the vector from it.

```
int[] tmp = {1,2,3,4};
vector<int> v(std::begin(tmp), std::end(tmp));
```

Comment: `tmp+sizeof(tmp)` this will lead to a segfault (if you are lucky)

Comment: @Matteo Thanks. Modified it to use std::end.

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade to a newer version for the C++11 support as noted by the comments.